# CSS learning console similar to tryruby.org or codecademy.com

Tags: javascript, css

When learning Ruby last year I took a quick course over at [TryRuby](http://tryruby.org) ... it's basically an interactive terminal that executes ruby commands and holds your hand through the language.

Likewise, over at [Codecademy](http://codecademy.com), they will have you perform increasingly more advanced JavaScript inside of a console so that you can learn the language.

Does a similar site/app/plugin exist that will take me through a series of exercises to get familiar with CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: `www.lynda.com` ? But you have to pay for subscription.

Comment: [css3please](http://css3please.com/) is great for testing and experimenting with css3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there are no such comprehensive online tutorials on CSS.

However, I'd recommend http://dabblet.com/ for learning HTML&CSS — it have some features that makes it greater than jsfiddle:

- live preview of what you type: you don't need to manually trigger it;
- -prefix-free by default, can be useful for novice, so you won't need to clutter with all this stuff from the start;
- awesome previewers for different properties (colors, gradients, dimensions, angles, etc.), so it would be easy to understand if you're doing something wrong.

BTW, it's a great idea — to create the open tutorials based on any one tool available online, I hope that someone would do it (if noone would, well, maybe I'll find some time for it).

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle.net will let you run HTML, CSS and Javascript in their console. They don't really provide in-context tips though.

If you're using a Mac, Coda has a good CSS tool that would be a nice way to get started. Espresso does something similar, but I use Coda so I can't really comment on Espresso.

If you use Firefox, download Firebug. If you're using Safari or Chrome, check out the Developer Console (right click -> inspect element). You can edit the styles on a page and watch them take effect immediately. It's a great tool.

Sorry I'm not really aware of anything exactly targeted to you, but hopefully the tools I mentioned will help. CSS is really something that won't take more than a few hours to get a handle on. From there it's just a matter of learning the different effects and options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or your browser's Development Tools which most probably lets you edit CSS dynamically.

Then, you can also try [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). That said, I tend to use the Dev Tools together with JSFiddle.